# I want to add a row for admob banner ads in my settings activity

Tags: android, admob

I want to add a row for admob banner ads in my settings activity without using an xml. How can I implement the same.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it dynamically by using something like following (where `content_main` is for example id of container `LinearLayout`)

```
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_main);

            AdView adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            adView.setAdUnitId(app.getAdUnitId());
            container.addView(adView);
```